# latexdiff with \cite commands gives output with apparently mismatched braces

Tags: citing, latexdiff

I have run into a problem with the markup that latexdiff adds around `\cite` commands. The MWE below, which is supposed to have been generated by latexdiff, doesn't compile because LaTeX doesn't recognise the closing brace for `\DIFdel`:

```
ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

The culprit is `\hspace{0pt}`: commenting this out prevents this error.

I have solved my immediate problem by manually deleting the string `\hspace{0pt}` from the difference file wherever it occurs, but obviously I'd rather not do this every time.

I have two questions: (1) why does LaTeX find a problem with the braces here in the first place, since they look matched to my human eyes (and to emacs!)? And (2) is there a way to prevent latexdiff from generating code that fails to compile in this way?

---

### MWE for LaTeX (note that I've deleted most of the latexdiff preamble)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% DIF PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF
%DIF UNDERLINE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdeltex}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF HYPERREF PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFdeltex{#1}}{}} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{Some text\mbox{%DIFAUXCMD
\cite{reference}}\hspace{0pt}%DIFAUXCMD
, and some more text.}
\DIFdelend

\bibliography{my_bib}
\end{document}
```

### MWE for latexdiff

#### `old.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{reference}, and some more text.

\bibliography{my_bib}
\end{document}
```

#### `new.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\bibliography{my_bib}
\end{document}
```

`latexdiff old.tex new.tex > diff.tex`

Comment: I think the problem is not really the `\hspace` command, but rather an incompatibility of the packages/code added by `latexdiff` with the current LaTeX version. LaTeX underwent some internal changes recently. If you add `\RequirePackage[2015/01/01]{latexrelease}` as first line of `diff.tex`, then the file works as it is.

Comment: Many thanks @gernot; if you add that as an answer I'll happily accept it! In the actual document, I couldn't roll back because I need more recent features in `amsmath`, but your discovery that `ulem` is the thing to avoid means that I can just call latexdiff with `-t CFONT` (to avoid styles using `ulem`) and all is well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This year (2020) LaTeX underwent some internal changes that introduce incompatibilities with some packages. It seems that `ulem.sty` is one of them, with the current version `ulem 2019/11/18` pre-dating the changes in the LaTeX format.

The differences file produced by `latexdiff` loads `ulem.sty` and uses the command `\sout` (strike out), which leads to the error.

```
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
...
\providecommand{\DIFdeltex}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
```

As a workaround, until the incomaptibility gets fixed, run `latexdiff` with the option `-t CFONT`, which avoids the use of `\sout` (proposed by @Ant in the comments).

Alternatively, add

```
\RequirePackage[2019/11/18]{latexrelease}
```

as the first line in the differences file. This will set back the LaTeX format to a state that is compatible.

Comment: Somehow removing "\hspace{0pt}" generated by latexdiff fixed this issue for me, before I found this great answer.

Comment: In my document \RequirePackage[2019/11/18]{latexrelease} caused LaTeX to hang.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Well, this is a non-normal behavior of `latexrelease`. If you care, post a question or file a bug report at [https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues)

Answer (score 22):

Germot already provided a good [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574311/39565).
However, it was not entirely satisfactory.
The `-t CFONT` option changes the formatting (it only uses colour, removing strike-out and underlining).
And while setting the `latexrelease` version to `2019/11/18` worked fine with OP's MWE, it failed in a more complex document.

So I sought to get rid of the real culprit, the `\hspace{0pt}`.

Since v1.0.1, latexdiff encloses citation (and a few other things such as siunitx commands) in `\mbox` commands in order to circumvent incompatibilities with ulem styling (the `\sout` and `\uwave` used by default).
However, this implies that line breaks no longer work within citations.
This was fixed in v1.2.1 by adding the `\hspace{0pt}` after the `\mbox`.
The changelog states that “change should not cause adverse behaviour otherwise”. Well, now it does!

My temporary fix was to edit the latexdiff source (`texmf-dist/scripts/latexdiff/latexdiff.pl`), and replace the `\hspace{0pt}` with a `\hskip0pt`.
The resulting PDF is identical to the one obtained with older versions.

---

### tl; dr:

Find script `latexdiff.pl` in your texlive installation directory¹, or executable `latexdiff` in your binaries directory and replace line 2734²:

```perl
push(@$retval,"\\mbox{$AUXCMD\n\\" . $1 . $2 . $3 ."}\\hspace{0pt}$AUXCMD\n" );
```

by

```perl
push(@$retval,"\\mbox{$AUXCMD\n\\" . $1 . $2 . $3 ."}\\hskip0pt$AUXCMD\n" );
```

---

¹ E.g. `/usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/latexdiff/latexdiff.pl`.
² Assuming you have latexdiff v1.3.1.1.