# Latexdiff on multi-file project

Tags: latexdiff

Could anyone who has used latexdiff on a big multi-file project (a thesis for example) explain how to get it to work? I'm using the "flatten" option. I have also manually copied over the glossary file, .sty file, and folder of images into the directory of the latexdiff tex file. I get errors when compiling telling me there's a forgotten endgroup.

Comment: Sorry to hear you are having troubles. However, it's impossible to diagnose the problem with the information given. It does not sound the error has anything to do with the multi-file approach. You can maybe see which part of the text is causing problems by opening the diff file and looking near the lines where the error message occurs. 
(Note also that for a thesis the resulting document with --flatten option might become very big, which will make the comparison quite slow, probably. You could try diffing individual chapters,. --flatten should be aware of \includeonly )

Answer (score 0):

Used the solution to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579662/132820. No idea why it worked but it worked.