# Sideways figure always rotates clockwise

Tags: rotating

I have a full page image I am displaying via

```
\usepackage{rotating}
...

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[counterclockwise]
        \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{visualizer}
    \caption[Quaternion visualizer GUI]{Quaternion visualizer GUI}
    \label{fig:QuatViz}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\afterpage{\clearpage}
```

I would like to rotate it CCW, but in spite of me specifying the counterclockwise argument, it rotates it clockwise. I've tried omitting the counter-clockwise argument (since from what I understand CCW is default), changing the image size and a few other things. This is the only sideways figure in my document. The clear page is so that the figure and all of the ones following it don't get pushed to the end of the chapter. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: are you using two sided document? it might be trying to put the captions towards the outer edges of the pages.

Comment: It is two sided and for the page it falls on, rotating it CW does put it on the outer edge. Is there no way to override that?

Comment: `sidewaysfigure` (and `sidewaystable`) has a fixed rotation direction (90 or -90 depending on the side for two-sided documents).  on p.5 of the documentation, it says "These are ‘fixed’ environments that just do 90 degree rotation, but it would be easy to parameterize this to do other rotations if needed (the mind boggles. . . )."  i suggest you get in touch with the developers and make that suggestion.  (in my view, all rotated figures/tables should have their bottom edges toward the right, at least for a left-to-right language.)

Comment: You can try the option '[figuresright]' for the rotating package. This will make all your sidewaysfigures turn counterclockwise irrespective of left or right pages.

Answer (score 7):

\usepackage[counterclockwise, figuresleft]{rotating}

Comment: I found a side-effect in the memoir document class. Applying this *did* rotate the sideways table I had, however it also adversely affected the layout of the word Chapter for each chapter by dropping it down about 2 to 3cm. I eventually removed the rotating package and used `\usepackage{pdflscape}` with a standard table which worked as well for me and the Chapter text was now back where it belonged.