# make caption alone in landscape

Tags: captions, rotating, landscape

I have an image that is already in landscape orientation (outside of LateX; in jpg format). Now I want to put the caption that comes along with it (typed in LaTeX) into landscape mode as well so that the image and caption are printed in the same page. Needless to say, the caption has to be to the right of the image (i.e. bottom of the image). Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Landscape figure in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50070/5764)

Answer (score 3):

If you must, use a `sidewaysfigure`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  % Place your image here
  \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A figure caption.}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\lipsum[4-7]

\end{document}
```