# Rotate & center landscape table in document containing \sidesubfloat

Tags: tables, landscape, sv-classes, sidesubfloat

How can I rotate and center a landscape table in a document based on the [svmono class](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book/blob/master/book/tex/svmono.cls), which also contains `\sidesubfloat` instances? It seems the use of
`floatrow` messes badly with the position of the landscape table (see "actual output" example). Even if this were not a problem, the rotation of the table is not as desired (see "desired output" example).

I've tried without luck the ideas in other posts in the forum... can someone please give me a hand? Thanks and regards, Jorge.

Example:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,vecarrow,twoside]{svmono}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=170mm,top=2.5cm,inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% For labels besides figures
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}

% Tables-related
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0ex
\belowrulesep=0ex
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

% For landscape stuff
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}
% Some text and a figure
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}}
\\
\vspace{1.0cm}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

% The landscape table
\clearpage
\vspace{4cm}
%\newgeometry{margin=3cm}   % This messes up the page number position!
%\thispagestyle{empty}       % This erases the page number!
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table*}[!h]
\centering%
\begin{tabular}{llccccccccccc}
\midrule[1pt]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}& & VLSI'17& ISSCC'17& VLSI'16& ISSCC'15& ISSCC'14& VLSI'17& ISSCC'17& VLSI'16& ISSCC'15& ISSCC'14\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}& \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{This work}}& [1]& [2]& [3]& [4]& [5]& [1]& [2]& [3]& [4]& [5]\\
\midrule[0.5pt]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Input range [V$_{\mathrm{pp}}$]}& 1.6& -& 2.0& -& 2.5& 2.0& -& 2.0& -& 2.5& 2.0\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Sampling rate [Sa/s]}& 600M& 500M& 9G& 2.5G& 500M& 1G& 500M& 9G& 2.5G& 500M& 1G\\
\midrule[0.5pt]
& LF input& 9.4& 9.1& -& 10.3& 10.5& 11.2& 9.1& -& 10.3& 10.5& 11.2\\
\multirow{-2}{*}{ENOB [bit]} & Nyquist& 9.06& 9.1& 10.7& 10& 10.3& 11& 9.1& 10.7& 10& 10.3& 11\\
\midrule[0.5pt]
\multirow{2}{*}{SNDR [dB]} & LF input& 58.1& 56.7& -& 64& 64.8& 69& 56.7& -& 64& 64.8& 69\\
& Nyquist& 56.3& 56.6& 66& 61.7& 64& 68& 56.6& 66& 61.7& 64& 68\\
\midrule[0.5pt]
\multirow{2}{*}{SFDR [dBc]}& LF input& 67.5& 73& 79& 80& 93& 86& 73& 79& 80& 93& 86\\
& Nyquist& 69.2& 69.2& 79& 73& 82& 82& 69.2& 79& 73& 82& 82\\
\midrule[0.5pt]
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Power [W]}& 14.2m& 6m& 2330m& 1150m& 550m& 1200m& 6m& 2330m& 1150m& 550m& 1200m\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{FOMW [J/conv.-step]}& 44f& 22f& 715f& 463f& 849f& 585f& 22f& 715f& 463f& 849f& 585f\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{FOMS [dB]}& 159.5& 162.8& 152.3& 152.1& 150.6& 154.2& 162.8& 152.3& 152.1& 150.6& 154.2\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Active area [mm$^{2}$]}& 0.621& 0.015& 5.1& -& 2.5& 18& 0.015& 5.1& -& 2.5& 18\\
\midrule[1pt]
\end{tabular}
\vspace{6pt}
\caption{Performance summary and comparison with state-of-the-art.}
\end{table*}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Actual output:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: May be you can try `\begin{table}...\end{table}` instead of `\begin{table*}[!h]...\end{table*}`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ruixi, that does improve the positioning of the table (at least now it's within the page). Any ideas on how to achieve the rotation and centering?

Comment: I think you are better off using the `rotating` package. Please take a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50071/164314).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Ruixi. Unfotunately, this doesn't work with svmono :( . I included a link to the class definition file in the original question (under the text "svmono class"). Another factor that is important is the presence of the text and \sidesubfloat instances (i.e. I'm not trying to create and empty document with a table, but this is to be embedded in an actual document, that's why I included these in my MWE)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note:

- The maintainer of `mathptmx` recommends users to use `newtx` instead.
- Please do *not* set `\aboverulesep=0ex` and `\belowrulesep=0ex`. The table looks awful.
- Please do *not* use `\midrule[...]`. You have `\toprule`, `\bottomrule` for thicker rules.
- Please do *not* add manual space `\vspace{6pt}` before the caption.

You can use the [`rotating`](https://ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package for your problem. More specifically, you need `\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}` in your preamble and use the `sidewaystable` environment.

<del>I don’t have the `svmono` class, so my illustration below uses `article`. I guess the `svmono` class used `\scriptsize` to get the your table to fit in one page. Please feel free to remove `\scriptsize` in your actual document.</del>

**Edit**: It seems that the `svmono` class has conflict with the `rotating` package. So a workaround is to load the package *before* the class declaration.

I’ve also noticed that you want the table *and* the caption (as a whole block) to be centered, while they are left aligned within the block. This is *NOT* how captions in the `svmono` class work! The captions are designed to be flushed left, as seen in the following illustration.

```
\RequirePackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,vecarrow,twoside]{svmono}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=170mm,top=2.5cm,inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Tables-related
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\aboverulesep=0ex
%\belowrulesep=0ex
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

% For landscape stuff
%\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{3.6cm}\\[1.0cm]% But why?
\rule{5cm}{3.6cm}
\caption{The caption is supposed to be flushed left!}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llccccccccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}& & VLSI'17& ISSCC'17& VLSI'16& ISSCC'15& ISSCC'14& VLSI'17& ISSCC'17& VLSI'16& ISSCC'15& ISSCC'14\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{}& \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{This work}}& [1]& [2]& [3]& [4]& [5]& [1]& [2]& [3]& [4]& [5]\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Input range [V$_{\mathrm{pp}}$]}& 1.6& -& 2.0& -& 2.5& 2.0& -& 2.0& -& 2.5& 2.0\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Sampling rate [Sa/s]}& 600M& 500M& 9G& 2.5G& 500M& 1G& 500M& 9G& 2.5G& 500M& 1G\\
\midrule
& LF input& 9.4& 9.1& -& 10.3& 10.5& 11.2& 9.1& -& 10.3& 10.5& 11.2\\
\multirow{-2}{*}{ENOB [bit]} & Nyquist& 9.06& 9.1& 10.7& 10& 10.3& 11& 9.1& 10.7& 10& 10.3& 11\\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{SNDR [dB]} & LF input& 58.1& 56.7& -& 64& 64.8& 69& 56.7& -& 64& 64.8& 69\\
& Nyquist& 56.3& 56.6& 66& 61.7& 64& 68& 56.6& 66& 61.7& 64& 68\\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{SFDR [dBc]}& LF input& 67.5& 73& 79& 80& 93& 86& 73& 79& 80& 93& 86\\
& Nyquist& 69.2& 69.2& 79& 73& 82& 82& 69.2& 79& 73& 82& 82\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Power [W]}& 14.2m& 6m& 2330m& 1150m& 550m& 1200m& 6m& 2330m& 1150m& 550m& 1200m\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{FOMW [J/conv.-step]}& 44f& 22f& 715f& 463f& 849f& 585f& 22f& 715f& 463f& 849f& 585f\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{FOMS [dB]}& 159.5& 162.8& 152.3& 152.1& 150.6& 154.2& 162.8& 152.3& 152.1& 150.6& 154.2\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Active area [mm$^{2}$]}& 0.621& 0.015& 5.1& -& 2.5& 18& 0.015& 5.1& -& 2.5& 18\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\vspace{6pt}
\caption{Performance summary and comparison with state-of-the-art.}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: rotated table]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Ruixi. Unfotunately, this doesn't work with svmono :(  . I included a link to the class definition file in the original question (under the text "svmono class"). Another factor that is important is the presence of the text and \sidesubfloat instances (i.e. I'm not trying to create and empty document with a table, but this is to be embedded in an actual document, that's why I included these in my MWE)...

Comment: @dontpanic Please check my updated answer. :)

Comment: Awesome, problem solved! Thanks you so much for help, Ruixi! :) 
W.r.t. the "indented" captions: indeed, the class enforces full flushing to the left, but in some situations (e.g. landscape tables narrower than the example above) it looks a little too much. Is there an easy way to "push" the captions a little towards the right? A simple \hspace seems to have no effect :\

Comment: @dontpanic Indeed, the `\hspace` method is not working. But to be honest: If the captions are meant to be flushed left, then I don’t think you should `\centering` the float contents in the first place. For your current table, I’d suggest an alternative: Since the table was very wide already, you could insert `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{5pt}%` between `\begin{sidewaystable}` and `\centering` to make it wider. You may choose a length other than `5pt` to make the table to fill up the entire text height. P.S. Your `\multicolumn`’s gobbled all left paddings. You may want to fix that.

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice! Widening the table solves the "look issue" for this table, but others in my document have fewer columns, and widening the table start to make them look awkward. I think I'll just let the caption flush, as intended by the class, no big problem. :) 
Just one last thing: what do you mean by "\multicolumn’s gobbled all left paddings"? and... how can I fix it?