# Caption above with the use of adjustbox and footnotesize under picture

Tags: floats, captions, rotating

I am trying to rotate a figure with the adjustbox statement as mentioned in [Rotate picture with caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/rotate-picture-with-caption). How ever I cant force the caption to be above and not below the plot inside this Code. Also I am trying to place the text of the footnotesize below the figure (at the place of the actual caption). Here is a short reproducible example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\section{Appendix}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\caption{Graphische Lösung: Veränderung der Konturlinien
     }\end{minipage}},rotate=90}
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-c}
        \label{fig:Lasscases}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \footnotesize{RSS und $t$ sind die Werte, bei denen die kleinste Konturlinie die Ecke der Raute tangiert *Das Beispiel unterstellt:  $\beta=(0.36, -0.1)$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{Appendix}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{adjustbox}{
  addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}
           \caption{Graphische Lösung: Veränderung der Konturlinien}}
          {\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
           \caption*{RSS und $t$ sind die Werte, bei denen die kleinste
                     Konturlinie die Ecke der Raute tangiert *Das Beispiel
                     unterstellt: $\beta=(0.36, -0.1)$.}
           \end{minipage}},
  rotate=90}
\includegraphics[width=.88\paperwidth]{example-image-c}
\label{fig:Lasscases}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: rotated figure with caption]

Comment: That is perfect ! Thank you. Just one Question. Is there a way to Center the figure in the middle of the picture. /centering doesnt work in that case

Comment: @Leo96 I’d suggest using the `rotating` package. You can take a look at [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444743/164314) to see how a table is rotated, and then decide whether to use the `rotating` package or not.

Comment: The rotating package is forcing the table/figure into a new side. Additionally I want that the section heading is also on that site

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox,capt-of}

\begin{document}
\section{Appendix}

\begin{adjustbox}{rotate=90}
  \begin{minipage}[c][\textwidth][s]{0.87\textheight}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}

  \vfill

  \captionof{figure}{Graphische Lösung: Veränderung der Konturlinien}
  \label{fig:Lasscases}
  \end{minipage}
\end{adjustbox}

\medskip\nopagebreak

{\footnotesize\noindent
RSS und $t$ sind die Werte, bei denen die kleinste Konturlinie 
die Ecke der Raute tangiert *Das Beispiel unterstellt:  $\beta=(0.36, -0.1)$.
\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]