# Portrait to Landscape page

Tags: landscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change certain pages into landscape/portrait mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode)

How to change the page from Portrait to Landscape? Page 1 should be in Portrait then Page 2-3 is in Landscape..

Comment: Why the downvote? Should we really downvote duplicates?

Comment: Indeed: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1462/downvoting-duplicates