# Making one page landscaped and all other portrait, is that possible?

Tags: xetex, pdfpages, landscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change certain pages into landscape/portrait mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode)

I'd like to have one page in landscape, in between of several other pages in portrait.

I know how to make all pages be rendered in landscape, but not just one page among other pages rendered in portrait.

The only way to do that, that I can think of, is to use `pdfpages` and assemble a final document from various PDFs rendered beforehand on their own. the Problem with this, is that I have to split the document in several parts, the part up to the landscape page, the landscape page itself, and everything after that. Should I be needing more of those landscape pages, this would turn more and more into chaos.

Is there a way to make one page appear in landscape?

Comment: Did you read [How to change certain pages into landscape/portrait mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337)?

Comment: polemon, please look at the link posted by @PaulGaborit. If it solves your problem, let us know and this one can be marked as a duplicate of that one. If it doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question and explain more in details, maybe providing some snapshots of the desired result.

Comment: Ah, Great! A few hours ago, I got a 404 from that link, seems to work now, though. Someone might wanna close this question now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `lscape` package as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```