# Making a page landscape, in a portrait written report

Tags: landscape

When using the following packages, is there any way to make a page landscape as opposed to portrait, i.e so that i can fit long equations in it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=Plum, linkcolor=Blue, urlcolor=RoyalBlue}
```

Comment: You can insert code indenting it by 4 spaces or using the link with two `{}`.

Comment: Have you tried the solution at [How to change certain pages into landscape/portrait mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try the lscape-package?

```
  \documentclass[english]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
  \usepackage{babel,blindtext}

  \usepackage{lscape}

  \begin{document}

  \Blindtext
  \begin{landscape}
  \Blindtext
  \end{landscape}
  \Blindtext
  \end{document}
```

I tried also with your packages - I had no problem:

```
\documentclass[english]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=Plum, linkcolor=Blue, urlcolor=RoyalBlue}

\begin{document}

\Blindtext
\begin{landscape}
\Blindtext
\end{landscape}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

If you have a problem, can you provide a MWE?

Comment: Please don’t answer questions that are likely to be a duplicate, especially not with a solution that duplicates the answer to another question. This just makes the knowledge management here so much harder and inefficient.