# How to switch from portrait to landscape page orientation?

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}        

\title{{\bf Your Research Title}}
\author{Your Name }     
\date{December 17, 2013}                    
%
\begin{document} \baselineskip=22pt
\maketitle
%
\begin{abstract}
You have to write the abstract here.
\end{abstract}  
%
\tableofcontents

%
\section{Introduction}
Albert Einstein (/ˈælbərt ˈaɪnstaɪn/; German: [ˈalbɐt ˈaɪnʃtaɪn] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the general theory of relativity, one of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum mechanics).[2][3] While best known for his mass–energy equivalence formula E = mc2 (which has been dubbed "the world's most famous equation"),[4] he received the 1921 Nobel Prize in Physics "for his services to theoretical physics, and especially for his discovery of the law of the photoelectric effect".[5] The latter was pivotal in establishing quantum theory.
Near the beginning of his career, Einstein thought that Newtonian mechanics was no longer enough to reconcile the laws of classical mechanics with the laws of the electromagnetic field. This led to the development of his special theory of relativity. He realized, however, that the principle of relativity could also be extended to gravitational fields, and with his subsequent theory of gravitation in 1916, he published a paper on the general theory of relativity. He continued to deal with problems of statistical mechanics and quantum theory, which led to his explanations of particle theory and the motion of molecules. He also investigated the thermal properties of light which laid the foundation of the photon theory of light. In 1917, Einstein applied the general theory of relativity to model the large-scale structure of the universe.[6]
\begin{figure} \centering \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{333.png} % d3.png: 900x400 pixel, 72dpi, 31.19x14.29 cm, bb=0 0 884 405 \caption{ MSCI Sector performances.} \label{Fig:16} \end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

I want to switch from portrait to landscape page orientation. How can I do it?

[image]

The texts have been rotated but the image. What else to do for the image?

Comment: Would this thread be useful?
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to change your whole document, you can use the `landscape` option from the `geometry` package

```
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
```

If it is just a part of the document (here, just the sole last page), you can use the `lscape` package

```
\usepackage{lscape}
```

and then

```
\begin{landscape}
\section{Introduction}
Albert Einstein (/ˈælbərt ˈaɪnstaɪn/; German: [ˈalbɐt ˈaɪnʃtaɪn] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the general theory of relativity, one of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum mechanics).[2][3] While best known for his mass–energy equivalence formula E = mc2 (which has been dubbed "the world's most famous equation"),[4] he received the 1921 Nobel Prize in Physics "for his services to theoretical physics, and especially for his discovery of the law of the photoelectric effect".[5] The latter was pivotal in establishing quantum theory.
Near the beginning of his career, Einstein thought that Newtonian mechanics was no longer enough to reconcile the laws of classical mechanics with the laws of the electromagnetic field. This led to the development of his special theory of relativity. He realized, however, that the principle of relativity could also be extended to gravitational fields, and with his subsequent theory of gravitation in 1916, he published a paper on the general theory of relativity. He continued to deal with problems of statistical mechanics and quantum theory, which led to his explanations of particle theory and the motion of molecules. He also investigated the thermal properties of light which laid the foundation of the photon theory of light. In 1917, Einstein applied the general theory of relativity to model the large-scale structure of the universe.[6]
\end{landscape}
```

However, if you use `pdflatex` and you intend to read your document on screen, you might want to use the `pdflscape` package, to have the page automatically rotated in your PDF viewer

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
...
\begin{landscape}
\section{Introduction}
Albert Einstein (/ˈælbərt ˈaɪnstaɪn/; German: [ˈalbɐt ˈaɪnʃtaɪn] ( listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German-born theoretical physicist who developed the general theory of relativity, one of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum mechanics).[2][3] While best known for his mass–energy equivalence formula E = mc2 (which has been dubbed "the world's most famous equation"),[4] he received the 1921 Nobel Prize in Physics "for his services to theoretical physics, and especially for his discovery of the law of the photoelectric effect".[5] The latter was pivotal in establishing quantum theory.
Near the beginning of his career, Einstein thought that Newtonian mechanics was no longer enough to reconcile the laws of classical mechanics with the laws of the electromagnetic field. This led to the development of his special theory of relativity. He realized, however, that the principle of relativity could also be extended to gravitational fields, and with his subsequent theory of gravitation in 1916, he published a paper on the general theory of relativity. He continued to deal with problems of statistical mechanics and quantum theory, which led to his explanations of particle theory and the motion of molecules. He also investigated the thermal properties of light which laid the foundation of the photon theory of light. In 1917, Einstein applied the general theory of relativity to model the large-scale structure of the universe.[6]
\end{landscape}
```

If you intent to rotate a single figure, you could use the `turn` environment from the `rotating` package; you then just have to specify the rotation angle, as follow

```
\usepackage{rotating}
...
\begin{figure} 
   \centering 
   \begin{turn}{90}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{333.png}
   \end{turn}
   \caption{ MSCI Sector performances.} 
   \label{Fig:16} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I understand but the graphics is not rotating to the horizontal. What to do for it? 

`\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.60]{333.png}
 % d3.png: 900x400 pixel, 72dpi, 31.19x14.29 cm, bb=0 0 884 405
 \caption{ MSCI Sector performances.}
 \label{Fig:16}
\end{figure}`

Comment: @ComplexGuy Please see my updated answer.