# Place sidewaystable together with text

Tags: tables, positioning

My sidewaystable is always placed on a separate page! How do I make it appear exactly where it is defined? Is that possible?

- text
- sidewaystable
- page break
- text

I've done something like this:

```
\begin{document}

\section{My Table}
\paragraph{}
Please print my table on this page!  

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{My Table}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}p{2.3cm}}
        \hline 
        A & B & C \\
        \hline      
        1 & 2 & 3 \\   
        \hline  
    \end{tabular}      
    \label{tab:mytable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that shows what you've been trying so far.

Comment: I've posted a MWE by editing my original post.

Comment: you are lacking a documentclass, and any definition of the `sidewaystable` environment.  Float positioning mainly depends on things such as page size that can not be deduced from an incomplete fragment

Comment: You don't say but you are using `rotating` package. `texdoc rotating` shows section 2.4 on float positioning which says that it only supports float pages not floats on a text page.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can also rotate the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,varwidth}
\begin{document}

\section{My Table}
\paragraph{}
Please print my table on this page!  

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \rotatebox{90}{\begin{varwidth}{\textheight}\centering

      \parbox{8cm}{\caption{My Table \label{tab:mytable}}}

        \begin{tabular}{p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}p{2.3cm}}
        \hline 
        A & B & C \\
        \hline      
        1 & 2 & 3 \\   
        \hline  
    \end{tabular}      
    \end{varwidth}}
\end{table}


\def\a{text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. text.. }
\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The`rotating`package documentation says that `sidewaystable` creates a page-sized float. If I understand you correctly you want the text above the table also rotated 90 degrees, right?

For this you could use the `lscape`package. Check this post: [How to change certain pages into landscape/portrait mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem so far:

```
\begin{document}

\section{My Table}
\paragraph{}
Please print my table on this page!  

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{My Table}
    \rotatebox{90}{
        \begin{tabular}{p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}p{2.3cm}}
            \hline 
            A & B & C \\
            \hline      
            OK, & I am good... & I will not float away! \\   
            \hline  
        \end{tabular}      
        \label{tab:mytable}
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For me, this solution is acceptable.