# How to split only 1 page of my documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} and add vertically a big table on a side

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, page-breaking

I am wondering on how to split in 2 a single page of my whole document, and add a table vertically. As a matter of fact the table is so large, that I used to reading it on a newpage in a landscape mode.

```
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
 ...
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
```

But now I'd like it to be disclosed as:

```
  %table(vertically to fit 1/2 page)               | %keep writing my text
```

Ps: Eventually on the following page I'd also like everything to revert back as usual on a single page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212827/place-sidewaystable-together-with-text

Comment: Do you sure, that half `\textheight` is bigger than `textwidth`? If it is, than see link which provide you @JohnKormylo, other wise don't change table orientation.

Comment: @Zarko: the problem with most of the related posts found online (@JohnKormylo et al., ....), lies in the size of my table (large enough). So when using `\begin{sidewaystable}`, my text on the right end side are embedded with this table on the left side resulting in a 'messy' output. A way around eventually found has consisted of resizing that table using a combination of  `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-xxx}` and `\small` to make it fit on a4 page document so as to carry forward quickly. it's not the ideal solution but at least it produces an acceptable table for reading purposes. Cheers.

Comment: See http://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/ ... reduce your table and fit it in text width. With your intention the article -- I', afraid will become "awful"

Comment: @Zarko: certainly it will, but thanks for the suggestion anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You have not provided any example so this is untested but

```
\usepackage{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
....
\twocolumn
\begin{sidewaystable}
...
\end{sidewaystable}

text.....
\onecolumn

more text...
```