# Horizontal page for largeTables

Tags: tables, landscape

I am new to LaTeX, I am writing a thesis, in which I have to add a table, the width of table is larger than text width and length can be fit in vertically. In order to fit the width of table, what is good idea to add table on horizontal page OR add it vertically without limitation of text width?

In order to add horizontally how I can do it? Response will be matter a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

If it is OK for you to have one page rotated as a landscape where to have only the table, try the [`lscape` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lscape):

```
\usepackage{lscape} 
...
\begin{document}

Text that will end up in portrait (normal) mode

\begin{landscape}
[insert table here that will be displayed horizontally]
\end{landscape}

Rest of the text here, again in portrait mode
```

See also this question: [How to change certain pages into landscape/portrait mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode)

Answer (score 15):

For one table (or figure) in landscape orientation you can use `\begin{sidewaystable} ... \end{sidewaystable}` (or `\begin{sidewaysfigure} ... \end{sidewaysfigure}`) from package `rotating`. For example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % optional

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\textbf{Here is inserted \texttt+sidewaystable+}.
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
\caption{Wide table}
    \label{tab:wide-item-tbl}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}}
    \hline
\lipsum[1]  &   \lipsum[2]  &   \lipsum[3]  &   \lipsum[4]  \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\lipsum[2-9]
\end{document}
```

Table will appear on the next page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is the thing that I was expecting. one more thing, the page does not rotate, only table rotate horizontally, I also would like to rotate the Page as well? any suggestion

Comment: how you expect that page will rotate? in viewer?

Comment: Yes, I mean to say in pdf viewer , we do not have to manually rotate the page, it should be in the same way as the previous page are.

Comment: @user7057295, about this is better to ask new question.

Comment: @Zarko do you know if it's possible to NOT rotate the caption of a rotated table?

EDIT: solved by myself by putting `tabular` only (and not the caption) inside `sideways` instead of putting `table` inside `sidewaystable`