# How to create this table using the rotating package?

Tags: tables, multicol, rotating, multirow

Like the title says, how do you create this table since this was taken from a book and I want to include it into my dissertation.

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciative.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the package "rotating" and the tags are:

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\begin{sidewaystable}
....table matter...
\end{sidewaystable}

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode#354) by [rcs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/118/rcs)

It explains how to landscape a particular page using the [lscape](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lscape) package.

Edit: after further research, you can have a look at the examples provided in this [PDF](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/float/examples.pdf) by Sebastian Rahtz and Leonor Barroca, it should give you some ideas.