# putting picture in landscape

Tags: graphics, floats, rotating, landscape

Here is the preamble i used

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} %Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
%\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt
%\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
and I want to put a picture in landscape mode. I did in this way which did not worked for me:

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{lhc_cross_section.jpg}
\caption{Cross sectional view of proton-proton collision.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Any suggestion will really be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "did not work"? How did it fail?

Comment: I am getting an error i.e 
l.269 \begin{landscape}
the picture is still in portrait mode.

Comment: It would help if you would mention which error you get. And a complete, compilable example would help too.

Comment: Have you loaded the `pdflscape` package? (I don't think the `landscape` environment is provided by default.)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337

Comment: By adding the \usepackage{pdflscape}the picture just moved to another page but still not in landscape mode.

Comment: `landscape` will always start a new page. Your code works for me, so I don't know what could be wrong. Do you use `pdflatex` to make the PDF, or something else?

Comment: yes i am using pdfltex chapter.tex

Comment: @Torborn T. it is necessary that the uploaded picture to the code should be in landscape?

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `.log` file? Have you tried other PDF viewers? (No idea if this is viewer dependent, so wild stab in the dark.) Note that the whole page is rotated, not the content on the page, and PDF viewers will show the rotated page.  So if you don't zoom out it might not be obvious that it's rotated.

Comment: It already worked. the whole page is rotated along with picture. thanks Torbjorn T.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. On the same page the title of chapter is written. Is it possible to remove the title only for the this page?

Comment: Try adding `\thispagestyle{empty}` right after `\begin{landscape}`.