# How can I rotate only one page or table inside a document?

Tags: tables, spacing, landscape, page

I have the following situation:

- A table is too large for a portrait PDF size
- I can split them up or make the side landscape. I tried both approaches, but they are not sufficient to solve the whole bunch!

I tried to make it landscape via the hints here: [How to change certain pages into landscape/portrait mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode)
It doesn't work. I get some strange error in the table, like the `[!htbp]` has an error. After removing them, same error was generated now by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` and so one...
So i tried with the command `\begin{sidewaystable}` to rotate only the table. It doesn't work... I tried the whole tips on the remarked page before...

**The target is to get this whole page on landscape format**, but only this one! In my tried solutions the page before also was in landscape mode... I would approximate it, if you can give me some hints to find a solution for this problem, thank you!
In the appendix is my code with some commented failed tries to reach this target and a picture how it looks!

```
\chapter{Bewertungsmatrix} \label{chap:bewertungsmatrix}
% \begin{sideways}
% \begin{turn}{90}
% \begin{sidewaysfigure}

% \begin{sidewaystable} 
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} 
\scalebox{0.93}{
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-17}
                                    & \multicolumn{16}{c|}{\textbf{Metrik Nr.}}                                     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Testv. Nr.}} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{11} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{13} & \textbf{14} & \textbf{15} & \textbf{16} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1}              & 1,3  & 2,0  & 1,7  & 2,0  & 2,0  & 63  & 93  & 97  & 57  & 37   & 23   & 10   & 23   & 7   & 103   & 53   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{2}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{3}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{4}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{5}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{7}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{8}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{9}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{10}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{11}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{12}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{13}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Beschreibungstext hier}
\label{tab:is-following...}
\end{table}
% \end{sidewaystable}

% \end{sidewaysfigure}
% \end{sideways}
% \end{turn}

% \newpage
% \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,pagesize}
% \recalctypearea
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I tried with the command \begin{sidewaystable} to rotate only the table. It doesn't work..."

Perhaps this will help (I've added the figure version also).

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tex_pic}
\caption{\lipsum[1]}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\clearpage
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\cline{2-17}
& \multicolumn{16}{c|}{\textbf{Metrik Nr.}}                                     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Testv. Nr.}} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{9} & \textbf{10} & \textbf{11} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{13} & \textbf{14} & \textbf{15} & \textbf{16} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1}              & 1,3  & 2,0  & 1,7  & 2,0  & 2,0  & 63  & 93  & 97  & 57  & 37   & 23   & 10   & 23   & 7   & 103   & 53   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{2}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{3}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{4}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{5}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{7}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{8}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{9}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{10}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{11}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{12}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{13}              &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\lipsum[1]}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @oliversm,
thanks for your solution! It works! In a second step I also tried it with

\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
...
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

and it is also OK.

Comment: @user216725, perhaps consider upvoting if it was helpful.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the reminder!