# Is there an easy way to transpose this table?

Tags: tables

I provided the source code and screenshot of the table I am trying to generate. The table is very wide, and I'm constrained to pretty wide horizontal margins. So I'm considering transposing the table. I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this? I have many of these tables, and it would take me a very long time to go through all of them.

Source code:

```
\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrr}
    \hline
    \hline
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Nominal}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1.20}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SG Case 1}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SG Case 2}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{SG Case 4}}
    \\\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(r){4-5}\cmidrule(r){6-7}\cmidrule(r){8-9}\cmidrule(r){10-11}
    &H&T&H&T&H&T&H&T&H&T\\\midrule
    0.1in.& 1.4e-03 & 1.6e-03 & 
    3.4e-05 & 1.0e-04 &
    7.2e-05 & 1.6e-04 &
    5.6e-05 & 1.3e-04 &
    4.4e-05 & 1.1e-04
\\
    0.3in.& 3.1e-04 & 1.3e-03 &
    5.0e-04 & 8.8e-04 &
    4.7e-04 & 1.1e-03 &
    5.1e-04 & 1.1e-03 &
    5.3e-04 & 1.0e-03
\\
    0.4in.& 3.1e-04 & 1.5e-03 &
    9.1e-04 & 1.4e-03 &
    8.4e-04 & 1.6e-03 &
    9.1e-04 & 1.7e-03 &
    9.6e-04 & 1.6e-03
\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: use ms excel transpose function

Comment: @jsbibra That works for latex source code?

Comment: nope only for tabular data

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Instead of trying to transpose the table, you could place it in a page with landscape orientation. See for example [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove repeated information, you can quite easily reduce the table significantly. With this approach, the table should easily fit into the quite narrow textwidth of a standard `article`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrr}
\toprule
& & & & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{SG Case}}\\
\cmidrule{6-11}
    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Nominal}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1.20}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{1}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{2}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{4}}
    \\\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(r){4-5}\cmidrule(r){6-7}\cmidrule(r){8-9}\cmidrule(r){10-11}
    &H&T&H&T&H&T&H&T&H&T\\
          & e-04 & e-03 & e-05 & e-04 & e-05 & e-04 & e-05 & e-04 & e-05  & e-04\\
\midrule
    0.1in.& 14   & 1.6  & 3.4  & 1.0  & 7.2  & 1.6  & 5.6  & 1.3  & 4.4  & 1.1  \\
    0.3in.& 3.1  & 1.3  & 50   & 88   & 47   & 11   & 51   & 11   & 53   & 1.0  \\
    0.4in.& 3.1  & 1.5  & 91   & 14   & 84   & 16   & 91   & 17   & 96   & 16   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```