# landscape setting but still portrait

Tags: formatting, koma-script, landscape

So I`m trying to get a landscape page mid document (to print 6 figures in one row) and was following the instructions of this [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430619/265265). 
Here is code fragment.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full, oneside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{typearea}

\title{hello}

% DOCUMENT 
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape, paper=A4, pagesize}
\recalctypearea

\chapter{Findings}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The landscape part of the PDF looks like this:
[image: generatedpdf]
Now to my problem: As you can see, it seems to still be in portrait mode (left and right empty spaces). Is there a setting I am missing? I work with TeXstudio 4.1.1 (git 4.1.1)
Using Qt Version 6.2.1, compiled with Qt 6.2.1 R. Operating system is macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pages are the right size; it just isn't recalculating the type area using the right settings. Try adding `DIV=current`. For other options, see the [KOMA-script documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), page 39.

```
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape, paper=A4, pagesize, DIV=current}
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: You can remove `\recalctypearea`. The type area is already recalculated because of `DIV=...`. Also `paper=A4` and `pagesize` can be removed. They are default.

Comment: good to know @esdd :)